# Apache Alias - Yii2

Tags: apache, yii2, apache2, yii2-advanced-app, apache2.4

I'm using Yii2 advanced template and I wonder if someone has a solution for the following scenario.

The web application has both frontend and backend interfaces.

The normal setup would be using Virtualhosts to setup sub domains:

- frontend.domain.com
- backend.domain.com

**The desired setup is:**

- domain.com = frontend
- domain.com/backend

I've been playing around with Apache Alias but no luck, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Below is my Virtualhost configs for reference:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/app/frontend/web"

    Alias "/backend" "/var/www/app/backend/web"

    <Directory "/var/www/app/backend/web">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /backend
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php

        # use index.php as index file
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        # ...other settings...
        # Apache 2.4
        Require all granted

        ## Apache 2.2
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you try to follow the guide on Yii website? https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to achieve what you want by Apache config. But you could create a symbolic link in the frontend folder linking to the web directory in backend:

`ln -s /path/to/backend/web /path/to/frontend/web/backend`